# Children's book - genius kid makes intramolecular level sword, builds spaceship out of cardboard

Tags: identification-request

I remember reading a children's book:

- There was a little boy who was a genius.
- He invents a very thin and sharp sword which can cut on an intramolecular level.
- He then slices his fishbowl, along with the fish, in half.
- In the end he builds a spaceship out of cardboard (I think) and goes to space.
- I think that the kid's name was Alex.
- At one point he talks about getting low marks in his social science test, and how he wanted to keep his secret of being a super genius.
- He also has an annoying little brother, I think

Can anyone identify this book?

Comment: You have a good start here with very specific story elements. Please read our guide for how to improve identification questions https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/4918 , perhaps it will remind you of other data you can give us. In particular, when did you read this book? Do you recall what the illustrations and cover look like? Please edit any new information into your question https://literature.stackexchange.com/posts/17048/edit

Comment: @b_jonas I added some more info

Answer (score 3):

This must be *[Gravity Buster: Journal #2 of a Cardboard Genius](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/452623.Gravity_Buster)*, by Frank Asch, the sequel to *Star Jumper: Journal of a Cardboard Genius*.

In the first book, the child genius Alex built a spaceship out of cardboard, in order to get as far away from his annoying younger brother, Jonathan, as possible. Unfortunately his creation was destroyed in a pillow fight. In the sequel he builds a spaceship twice as big as the original, and equipped with many amazing features.

As recalled in the question, one of the devices Alex builds is the "quantum sword":

> Theoretically my supersword was sharp enough to slice molecules in
> half! Of course, a sword like that would be a great asset aboard the
> Star Jumper [his spaceship]. At the very least I could use it to
> defend myself against hostile aliens. But I was sure it would come in
> handy for lots of other purposes - like slicing open asteroids to look
> for minerals and drinkable water or performing delicate surgeries

While testing the sword, Alex sneezes and accidentally slices his fishbowl, and pet fish, into two halves. The cut was so perfect, however, that no water leaked out and the fish continued to swim unperturbed, due to "quantum dislocation".

The series continues to a third book, where Alex builds a time machine (out of cardboard again, naturally).